# Connect VS 2017 to TFS 2005, Compatibility issue?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, tfs-2005

Is it possible to connect Visual Studio 2017 to a Team Foundation Server 2005 SP1? Version of microsoft.teamfoundation.server.dll = 8.0.50727.762

I tried to connect with http://servername:8080/ (by using the server url servername//) and with http://servername:8080/tfs (by using server url servername)

Both give an error TF31002: Unable to connect. The remote server returned an error 404.

Using Visual Studio 2005 or 2008 the connection goes without a problem.

I can't find a compatibility overview of Visual Studio / possible TFS versions.

Comment: Can you use Fiddler to compare which URL is actually used to access the TFS server.

Comment: Why are you still running a 12 year old version of TFS? It's long past time to upgrade.

Comment: Sometimes you don't have the possibility to change things by a customer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be possible but is not a supported scenario according to [TFS Requirements and compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/vsts/tfs-server/requirements), see section about Client compatibility where Team Foundation Server 2008 is the oldest mentioned as supported partly/fully by Visual Studio 2005-2017.